# IBM IHS Webserver fixpack issue

Tags: websphere, middleware

I am upgraded **IBM WebSphere, IHS, Plugins** from `8.0.0.9` to `8.0.0.13` after applying **Fixpack** to **IHS** it shows some ***configuration error***.

Now when I access the application from IHS URL it showing `404 error`.

There is a configuration **IHS** and node.

The below snapshot shows the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that you simply didn't start the administration server (bin/adminctl start)

Comment: Already started IHS,Applicationserver.

servers are started.
Webserver started.

the exact issue is there is a configuration missing between IHS and Node.

Comment: I'm skeptical because three servers should be started and you named two.  appserver, IHS, IHS admin server

What "exact issue" are you referring to beyond 'doesn't work'? That's not exact at all.